Get data to display on a modal using Python, HTML and CSS
I would like this data to be displayed in my modal which rests on a template managehouses.html. the code that fetches the data from the database is
def housetypes():
  cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    try:
      cur.execute("SELECT * FROM housetypes")
      housetypes = cur.fetchall()
  except MySQLdb.Error as e:
      flash(f"An error occurred: {e}", "error")
      housetypes = []
  finally:
      cur.close()
  return render_template('managehouses.html', housetypes=housetypes)

The following is my modal body:
<div class="modal-body">
   <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Housetype ID</th>
                <th scope="col">Housetype Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Rent Amount</th>
                <th scope="col">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for row in housetypes %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ row['housetypesid'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ row['housetypename'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ row['rentamount'] }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

It only displays the headers without the data. I expected the data to display on the modal.

What does the render_template() function do? How looks like this function? Do you get a response from your database query?

I can see no problem with either your python or jinja2 code. You do seem to be missing a semicolon at the end of your SQL though.

Let's try fixing the issue of the headers displaying without the data by ensuring the loop and HTML structure are properly formatted.
Python
 from flask import render_template, flash import MySQLdb
 
 def housetypes():
     cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
     try:
         cur.execute("SELECT * FROM housetypes")
         housetypes = cur.fetchall()
     except MySQLdb.Error as e:
         flash(f"An error occurred: {e}", "error")
         housetypes = []
     finally:
         cur.close()
     return render_template('managehouses.html', housetypes=housetypes)

HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Manage Houses</title>
  <!-- Include your CSS and other head elements here -->
</head>
<body>

<!-- Your other HTML content -->

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="houseTypesModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="houseTypesModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="houseTypesModalLabel">House Types</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Housetype ID</th>
              <th>Housetype Name</th>
              <th>Rent Amount</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {% for row in housetypes %}
            <tr>
              <td>{{ row['housetypesid'] }}</td>
              <td>{{ row['housetypename'] }}</td>
              <td>{{ row['rentamount'] }}</td>
              <td>
                <!-- Define your action buttons here, for example: -->
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Include your JavaScript libraries, for example: jQuery, Bootstrap JS -->
</body>
</html>

I'm assuming the table in the modal should now display the following if the data is correctly fetched:

Housetype ID | Housetype Name    | Rent Amount | Action
1            | Homer             | 742         | [Edit] [Delete]
2            | Springfield       | 1000        | [Edit] [Delete]
...

Let us know what happens. Thanks:)
